# How to remove ^M character from file which is generated on Fly using Perl Script

Tags: perl

I am creating normal txt file on the basis of provided configuration so when I am trying to remove Control M from file it is giving me error as

```
syntax error at CreateConfig.pl line 141`, near `perl -p -i -e "s/\r\n/\n/g`
Execution of `CreateConfig.pl` aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Code line:

```
system("perl -p -i -e "s/\r\n/\n/g" OptionFile.txt");
```

Can anyone has any suggestion for same?

Comment: In the search pattern try writing ctll+V+M(Holding on control) then run the above code line.

Comment: On which platform are you executing the perl code? Windows? Unix/Linux?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably `OptionFile.txt` has been created on a Windows system? Rather than using a `system` call to edit the file in place before opening it, it is probably better to handle this when you read from the file

If you write

```
open my $fh, '<:crlf', 'OptionFile.txt' or die $!;
```

then the CR (control-M) characters will be removed by Perl on input

Alternatively, if you already have a `chomp` in your read loop then you can replace that with `s/\R\z//`. `\R` matches any standard line ending, and so will strip the trailing CR LF from a Windows file

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest double quotes inside doublequote. Use single quotes instead one of them.

If you're calling it from Perl, use single quotes for the outer ones, otherwise Perl will interpolate the `\r` and `\n`. Or, replace it with code that does the same directly without calling Perl again. The best place to remove them would be the same where you read the file.

Comment: Removing the carriage returns when you actually read the data file would probably make more sense.